# Keep user sign in In office 365

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms

Hello Developers I'm using Xamarin Forms I have two method to authenticate user :

1 : the user enter username and password

2 : the user can authenticate with their Office 365 account .

for the first method when the user enter his username and password and check if username and password existe ... 
i do this 
app.Properties["logged"] = "true";

same for Office but i always go back to the Authentification Page

this is the App.cs

```
        if (this.Properties.ContainsKey("logged") && Application.Current.Properties["logged"].ToString() == "true")
        {
            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MasterMenuPage());
        }
        else
        {
            if (this.Properties.ContainsKey("currentConfig"))
            {
                MainPage = new NavigationPage(new AuthentificationPage());
            }
            else
            {
                MainPage = new NavigationPage(new ChoixEcole());
            }
        }
```

Comment: have you used the debugger to step through you code and verify your logic?

Comment: No @Jason it  was working fine i only changed the azure Active directory connection